# Firebase loading data slowly into flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I need to get data from firebase into flutter app but I have about 200 lines of data and would like to find a way to make it better and stream line and this is two weeks after the app went live so we need it to work for like 10000 lines later on

```
static obtainWorkData(context) async {
    List<String> workDataKeys = [];
    List<String> workInProDataKeys = [];
    List<String> workDoneDataKeys = [];

    await taskDef.get().then(
      (DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.exists) {
          Map<dynamic, dynamic> keys = snapshot.value;
          keys.forEach((key, value) {
            if (key != 'taskNo') {
              if (snapshot.value[key]['progress'] == null) {
                workDataKeys.add(key);
              } else if (snapshot.value[key]['progress'] == 'Started') {
                workInProDataKeys.add(key);
              } else {
                workDoneDataKeys.add(key);
              }
            }
          });
        }
      },
    );

    Provider.of<Current>(context, listen: false).clearWorkData();
    Provider.of<Current>(context, listen: false).clearWorkInProData();
    Provider.of<Current>(context, listen: false).clearDoneData();

    for (String key in workDataKeys) {
      await taskDef.child(key).once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.value != null) {
          var job = JobCart.fromSnapshot(snapshot);
          Provider.of<Current>(context, listen: false).updateWorkData(job);
        }
      });
    }
    for (String key in workInProDataKeys) {
      await taskDef.child(key).once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.value != null) {
          var job = JobCart.fromSnapshot(snapshot);
          Provider.of<Current>(context, listen: false).updateWorkInProData(job);
        }
      });
    }
    for (String key in workDoneDataKeys) {
      await taskDef.child(key).once().then(
        (DataSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.value != null) {
            var job = JobCart.fromSnapshot(snapshot);
            Provider.of<Current>(context, listen: false)
                .updateWorkDoneData(job);
          }
        },
      );
    }
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }
```

Comment: Use Pagination. Exp. [medium](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/pagination-in-flutter-with-firebase-firestore-96d6cc11aef2) [pub](https://pub.dev/packages/paginate_firestore)

Comment: In the case where you are doing a dashboard how should I go about it, pull it as aggregated.

Comment: Firebase is incredibly fast and loading 200 "lines of data" should happen almost instantly. Even 10,000 "lines of data" should not take very long. That being said we don't know what "lines of data" means or what your internet performance is (if you're using 300 baud dial up, it will be slower). If you can clarify what a "line of data" is and also troubleshoot your code a bit, then update your question, we may be able to spot somthing. I would suggest commenting out all but the firebase read and see how long it takes to return those 200 lines.